# git clone fatal: cannot create work tree dir permission denied

Tags: git, bash, github, intellij-idea

so I'm trying to clone a repository from git, into a folder i know I have write access in.

I'm trying to clone it using IntelliJ's built in VCS capabilities, and the git bash program from git-scm.com Both of them return the following error:

```
fatal: could not create work tree dir '<repo name>' : 
Permission denied
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Alright, I figured out what was wrong, the folder that shared a name with the repo had read only on it. But when I tried to change the attributes I was denied permission, even with admin, will I need to make a linux live cd just to remove that folder or what?

Comment: `chmod 644 [directory]` and `chown user:group [directory]`?

Comment: chmod gives me permission denied, even as administrator, chown says it can't perform the operation because it is a directory

Comment: `sudo chmod ... ` or `sudo chown <user> ...`

Comment: After much pain with Windows' horrible everything I figured it out. chown chose to work my second time around, thanks!

Comment: you can run sudo git clone <url>

Answer (score 17):

Use sudo

```
sudo git clone <url>
```

Comment: Note: using sudo git clone can cause error: "git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)."

Github documentation discourages using sudo with git: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey

Answer (score 4):

The error is pretty simple. You don't have permissions on the given directory.

You can do several things but the most simple one is to try and clone the repository vi `git bash`

```
# go to any other directory where you have the permissions to write to
cd <some path>

# Check to see if you have permissions:
mkdir dummy

# Now once you have verified that you have write permissions -
# clone the project from the command line
git clone <url>
```

Once you have cloned the project - open it in IntelliJ's.

Answer (score 2):

One thing is very clear that you don't have permissions on the given directory. So either you can do cloning or simply run the application by selecting **Run as Administration** as shown in the image.[image]

Later on, you can use git clone https://github.com/forcedotcom/EMP-Connector.git

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

After you have checked the directory permission (make sure you've got write access) try the below steps:

```
cd ~/
mkdir code
cd code
git clone https://github.com/repo-name
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sudo git clone can cause error: "git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)."

Github documentation discourages using sudo with git: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey

More robust way is to clone the repository first in to a place where you have permissions and then move the repository if needed.

First clone repository in your home directory:

```
cd ~
git clone git@github.com:repository.git
```

After cloning you can move cloned repository to desired folder

```
sudo mv repository /new-dir
```

Answer (score -1):

First open run your cmd as adminstrator, next move to the folder where you want to clone the repository.type the clone command.

Comment: As far as I understand OS in the question is not windows

Comment: Git Bash is a Windows thing, so I think the OS in indeed Windows.